# Generate a dynamic sql query using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a senario that I have to generate a dynamic string using python I am getting a array with some strings like this :

```
array = ["1","2", "5"]
```

and a `ID = "1"` and they both will merge in a way I want to pass this string as Values to a Sql query using like this

I am creating a string like this :

```
query := fmt.Sprintf("INSERT INTO %s(%s) VALUES(%s)", "Persons1", strings.Join(Columns, ","), values)
```

so this string I will be passing on uper one would be something like which I am generating from that array and a constant ID

```
values = ("1", "1"), ("1", "2"), ("1", "5")
```

So that I can generate a query from this like this

```
INSERT INTO Persons1 (LastName, FirstName) VALUES ("1", "1"), ("1", "2"), ("1", "5");
```

Comment: Do you need Go or Python?

Comment: @Pitto  sorry question updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use basic string manipulation tools to achieve the result:

```
query = "INSERT INTO Persons1 (LastName, FirstName) VALUES ";
id = "1"
array = ["1" ,"2" , "5"]

for item in array:
    add_to_query = '("{}", "{}"), '.format(id, item)
    query += add_to_query
    
query = query[:-2] # This will remove the last two characters from the query ", "
query += ";" # This will add the right character to terminate a SQL query

print(query)
```

**Output**

```
INSERT INTO Persons1 (LastName, FirstName) VALUES ("1", "1"), ("1", "2"), ("1", "5");
```

[More info about slicing](https://www.w3schools.com/python/gloss_python_string_slice.asp)
[More info about string format](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_format.asp)

Comment: 1 correction  I am not having this  want to generate this   `values = ("1", "1"), ("1", "2"), ("1", "5")` .  have a array of  `array = ["1" ,"2" , "3"]`  and a `ID="1"` which will append in all  values pair

Comment: Can you please elaborate?
So the only thing you have is array = ["1" ,"2" , "3"]? and ID="1"?
How are you supposed to generate the values?

Comment: Ah ok I think I understand

Comment: yes I have these two only , `values = ("1", "1"), ("1", "2"), ("1", "5")`  is pair of  like this  `values = ( ID, array[0]), (ID, array[1]), (ID, array[2])`   .  sorry 3 written by mistake sir

Comment: Please check the new version